# ImageView not displaying image set programmatically

Tags: android, imageview

I have an `ImageView`:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconIv"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                tools:srcCompat="@sample/icon[1]" />
```

// I've also tried usual ImageView with no success

It's fully visible and I see its bounds in UiAutomatorViewer.

When I set image from XML, for example, `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_telephone"` it's displayed normally.

If I set the same image **programmatically** `iconIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_telephone)` it does not display image.

It also does not work with Picasso:

```
Picasso
    .with(iconIv.context)
    .load(R.drawable.ic_telephone)
    .into(iconIv)
```

or

```
Picasso
    .with(iconIv.context)
    .load(appTask.iconUrl)
    .into(iconIv)
```

or with Glide:

```
Glide
    .with(iconIv.context)
    .load(appTask.iconUrl)
    .into(iconIv)
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need **get()**
https://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(R.drawable.ic_telephone)
    .into(iconIV);
```

Comment: It does not work even with direct set: `iconIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_telephone)`

Comment: Your context is wrong ,you need to use one of those  MainActivity.this or this

Comment: do you see `Context` here `iconIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_telephone)`?

Comment: it doen't matter which context is used in current situation

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, try this, AppCompatImageView you need that.
I just tested FYI

```
 private AppCompatImageView mImv;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mImv = findViewById(R.id.iconIv);
        mImv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(TAG, "onClick: ");
            }
        });
        mImv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save);
```